# Multilayer perceptron for ocr works with only some data sets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ocr, momentum

**NEW DEVELOPMENT**

I recently used OpenCV's MLP implementation to test whether it could solve the same tasks. OpenCV was able to classify the same data sets that my implementation was able to, but unable to solve the one's that mine could not. Maybe this is due to termination parameters (determining when to end training). I stopped before 100,000 iterations, and the MLP did not generalize. This time the network architecture was 400 input neurons, 10 hidden neurons, and 2 output neurons.

I have implemented the multilayer perceptron algorithm, and verified that it works with the XOR logic gate. For OCR I taught the network to correctly classify letters of "A"s and "B"s that have been drawn with a thick drawing untensil (a marker). However when I try to teach the network to classify a thin drawing untensil (a pencil) the network seems to become stuck in a valley and unable to classify the letters in a reasonable amount of time. The same goes for letters I drew with GIMP.

I know people say we have to use momentum to get out of the valley, but the sources I read were vague. I tried increasing a momentum value when the change in error was insignificant and decreasing when above, but it did not seem to help.

My network architecture is 400 input neurons (one for each pixel), 2 hidden layers with 25 neurons each, and 2 neurons in the output layer. The images are gray scale images and the inputs are -0.5 for a black pixel and 0.5 for a white pixel.

**EDIT:**

Currently the network is trainning until the calculated error for each trainning example falls below an accepted error constant. I have also tried stopping trainning at 10,000 epochs, but this yields bad predictions. The activation function used is the sigmoid logistic function. The error function I am using is the sum of the squared error.

I suppose I may have reached a local minimum rather than a valley, but this should not happen repeatedly.

Comment: Are you experiencing issues at the classification (prediction for unseen input) or training time? It sounds like it's training time that is causing problems, but it's not clear. Also, you should state what activation functions and loss function you're using on the layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momentum is not always good, it can help the model to jump out of the a bad valley but may also make the model to jump out of a good valley. Especially when the previous weights update directions is not good.

There are several reasons that make your model not work well.
The parameter are not well set, it is always a non-trivial task to set the parameters of the MLP.

An easy way is to first set the learning rate, momentum weight and regularization weight to a big number, but to set the iteration (or epoch) to a very large weight. Once the model diverge, half the learning rate, momentum weight and regularization weight.

This approach can make the model to slowly converge to a local optimal, and also give the chance for it to jump out a bad valley.

Moreover, in my opinion, one output neuron is enough for two class problem. There is no need to increase the complexity of the model if it is not necessary. Similarly, if possible, use a three-layer MLP instead of a four-layer MLP.

Comment: I am sorry but there are a few things I do not understand. By setting the iteration to a large "weight" do you mean I should stop after a large number of epochs? Also I am checking the error with respect to the trainning set. When you say "diverge" are you saying I should be checking the error with respect to the validation set? One more thing, do I need to use regularization? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the latency. What I mean is to run the algorithm multiple times. The diverge means that the error becomes larger and larger and never reduces. The error can be measured during training. For example, calculate the average error every 50 epoch. It's better if you use regularization.

Comment: I am still having problems, but I don't see why it is still is not working. It seems to have decreased the error, but the error is still to big.

Comment: There are a couple of main reasons: (1) Are there enough training data? (2) Are the features you extracted enough? (3) The model may trapped in the local optimum. (4) If you have enough training data, try to increase the complexity of the model. (5) Continuously adjust the parameters.

Comment: I think I figured out why it doesn't work now, although maybe I should have figured this out earlier. It seems there are not enough training examples for the model to correctly classify new letters (one's not included in the training set). Pherhaps it worked with the other data sets because they are easier to classify. Thanks for the help.